# Как посчитать количество строк по каждой комбинации не группируя их? Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такая таблица:

```
| user_id | product_id | action
+---------+------------+--------
| 1       | 1          | viewed
+---------+------------+--------
| 1       | 1          | liked
+---------+------------+--------
| 1       | 1          | bought
+---------+------------+--------
| 1       | 2          | viewed
+---------+------------+--------
| 1       | 2          | bought
+---------+------------+--------
| 2       | 1          | viewed
+---------+------------+--------
| 2       | 1          | liked
+---------+------------+--------
```

Необходимо посчитать количество товаров над которым пользователь совершал какое-либо действие. При этом неизвестно какие значения могут быть в таблице action. Тут конечно напрашивается банальное решение, например такое:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(product_id)
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, product_id FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id, product_id
) my_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Оно вернёт мне это:

```
| user_id | count 
+---------+-------
| 1       | 2
+---------+-------
| 2       | 1
```

Но я хочу получить не только пользователя и количество товаров над которым он совершал какие-либо действия, но и сами эти товары. Я ожидаю:

```
| user_id | product_id | count
+---------+------------+-------
| 1       | 1          | 2
+---------+------------+-------
| 1       | 2          | 2
+---------+------------+-------
| 2       | 1          | 1
+---------+------------+-------
```

Т.е. проще говоря мне нужно получить уникальные комбинации user_id и product_id и сопоставить им количество таких комбинаций в результате. Если вы всё равно не совсем поняли что я хочу, могу ещё сказать так: Получить количество уникальных комбинаций user_id и product_id. К каждой такой комбинации добавить количество товаров, над которым данный user_id совершал какое-либо действие.

Казалось бы сделай 2 запроса и не парься. Но проблема в том, что эта таблица выдуманная и вместо `my_table` в:

```
SELECT ... FROM my_table
```

Будет сложный подзапрос, который выполнять 2 раза будет довольно ресурсозатратно. Моя версия mysql не поддерживает синтаксис `WITH .. AS`. Посчитать количество таких комбинаций с помощью ЯП выбрав только уникальные комбинации из БД тоже не получится =)

Comment: *Оно вернёт мне это:* Нет. *Я ожидаю:* `SELECT user_id, product_id, COUNT(*) FROM (твой запрос) AS data GROUP BY user_id, product_id`. PS. Показанный желаемый результат не соответствует показанным исходным данным.

Comment: @Akina Почему не соответствует? Возможно вы не поняли что я хочу. Там значения как бы дублируются для каждого user_id и если user_id одинаковый, то эти значения тоже будут одинаковыми. Поправил запрос, теперь возвращает то что и показано =)

Comment: То есть `count` в последнем результате - это `COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)`, а не количество записей для пары (юзер-товар)? Тогда укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Это потому что мне нужно посчитать НЕ количество ДЕЙСТВИЙ пользователя над товаром, а количество ТОВАРОВ, над которыми пользователь совершал действия)

Comment: А такой вариант: `SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(product_id), COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) FROM (..) AS mytable GROUP BY user_id` - устроит? или надо непременно отдельную запись на каждый товар?

Comment: @Akina сейчас попробую ваш вариант, версия mysql 5.7

Comment: На версии 5,7 получить строго указанный вывод одним запросом, не выполняя подзапрос, дающий исходные данные, дважды - практически нереально. Разве что в хранимой процедуре с использованием временной таблицы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А такой вариант:

```sql
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(product_id), COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) 
FROM (сложный запрос) AS mytable 
GROUP BY user_id
```

устроит?

На версии MySQL 5.7 возможно разве что решение в формате хранимой процедуры:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_output ()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
    SELECT ... (Ваш сложный запрос);
SELECT user_id, product_id, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.product_id)
    FROM temp t1
    JOIN temp t2 USING (user_id, product_id)
    GROUP BY user_id, product_id;
DROP TABLE temp;
END
```

и потом

```sql
CALL get_output;
```

В процедуре после сохранения результата во временной таблице можно уже крутить её как угодно (включая ограничение выводимых товаров на юзера и пр.). Также следует посмотреть на объём данных - если он велик, лучше подстраховаться и создавать постоянную, а не временную, таблицу.

Comment: Я ещё раз посмотрел, такое решение не подойдёт =( Потому что я потом беру из полученных строк не больше 10 для каждого user_id, иначе время выполнения сильно возрастает

Comment: Вы что-то говорили про процедуру, но я не знаю что это, это будет сложно сделать?

Comment: @Inventor Добавил.

Comment: Я не работал с процедурами. Но если я правильно понял, то я должен сделать всего 1 раз `CREATE PROCEDURE`. А потом каждый раз, когда мне нужны данные делать `CALL get_output`?

Comment: @Inventor Всё верно. Если надо - можно добавить процедуре параметры и соответственно использовать их при формировании требуемого вывода внутри процедуры.

Comment: Всё круто, но есть проблема, у меня некоторые `join`, условия для них и блок `where`. Генерируются динамически с помощью ЯП. Параметры как я понимаю не могут менять таблицы которые джоинятся и условия для них (Или могут?). Возможно в такой ситуации лучше создавать каждый раз новую процедуру? Но много времени занимает создание процедуры? Или это происходит мгновенно? Не надо всё расписывать, просто скажите как лучше поступить в такой ситуации, я найду информацию как это сделать =)

Comment: Нашёл такой вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure Разберусь. Спасибо вам. Если бы тут была рубрика "лучший администратор баз данных" я бы проголосовал за вас =)

Comment: @Inventor *много времени занимает создание процедуры?* Это практически мгновенная операция. Всё, что она делает - проверяет синтаксическую корректность и записывает текст процедуры в служебную таблицу. *Возможно в такой ситуации лучше создавать каждый раз новую процедуру?* Зависит от формируемого текста. Если его можно параметризовать - то просто передаём нужные параметры в процедуру и используем их в запросе, либо в процедуре формируем требуемый текст запроса и выполняем динамическим SQL. PS. Я не администратор БД и не программист, я сетевой администратор.

Comment: Хорошо, думаю буду в процедуре формировать нужный мне sql